# Why aren't there any updates showing up?

Tags: updates, update-manager

I tried everything, but Ubuntu simply doesn't show any updates. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

You have to click 'Check' in Update manager And the enter your password . [image]

Answer (score 1):

try opening the terminal and typing `sudo apt-get update` after it finishes run `sudo apt-get upgrade` If you get the following message

> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Then there are no newer versions of your software available, and you should check at a later time.